# Any way to access "metadata categories" in Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-workspace

Since April 2019, Google Drive introduced "metadata categories" as a Beta Program. This new feature lets users "tag" or categorize files, in order to get a better organization.
It is a GSuite Business-only feature.

Here are some links about this new beta feature.
[Documention of the new feature](https://support.google.com/a/answer/9292382?hl=en)
[Blog post mentioning the release](https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2019/04/drive-metadata-beta.html)

Has anybody found a way to access this new information from the Google Drive API? Or is it not yet available?
It doesn't seem to be related to the "properties" key/value array already available through the API, documented [here](http://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/dyn/drive_v3.files.html#get).